# Xcode 11 - XCUITest -> is there a way to handle this exception "Failed to get matching snapshots"?

Tags: ios, xcuitest

Is it possible to catch the following exception?

> "Failed to get matching snapshots"

Most of the stability issues with XCUITest is due to not having a proper method to wait for element to exist.  Tried exists(), waitforexistence(),xctwaiter waits etc. In all cases it fails randomly with above error.  Is there a way we have handle this exception do a retry in our tests itself.

Comment: Please add some sample code and output generating the failure. You may also wish to review this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429118/ui-testing-fails-with-error-failed-to-get-snapshot-within-15-0s

Answer (score 0):

You should stick to combination of two methods 
Use it for every flaky element

```swift
button.waitForExistence()
button.tap()
```

Comment: The problem, is waitForExistence() itself throws error..  So is there a way to catch that exception ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/2879412-waitforexistence 

No it does not. It only returns Boolean value indicating waiting was successful.

Comment: yes, I am aware of the documentation part, but this is the case when you actually run the test.  You get an exception and the test fails.  Example Error log:    Checking existence of `"ios close icon" Button`
    t =   117.83s         Assertion Failure: Extensions.swift:171: Failed to get matching snapshots: Error getting main window kAXErrorServerNotFound
    t =   117.85s     Capturing element debug description

Comment: Well, it is not a thrown error, it is a fail. It is hard to tell what caused it since a very little description of your problem. As mentioned by ablarg earlier, the question is not very informative.