# "Failed to get matching snapshots: Timed out while evaluating UI query." in XCUITest

Tags: swift, snapshot, evaluation, bulk, xcuitest

I'm writing the UI tests for an application that contains huge cells(~ 1000) in its tableview. Trying to access the cell elements will show the below error:

> Failed to get matching snapshots: Timed out while evaluating UI query.

**Scenarios:**

- If I try to get the cells count by `XCUIApplication().tables.firstMatch.cells.count`, it throws the exception
- Printing `XCUIApplication().debugDescription` for the *first time* prints the whole hierarchy (though, it takes ~10secs to print)
- After that, If I try to print the exact same line `XCUIApplication().debugDescription`, throws an exception

I can not check the cells counts and can't able to access the cell elements. The system is trying to evaluate all UI elements whenever I access an element in the `XCUIApplication()`.

This is the expected behaviour, so I thought of making a copy of `XCUIApplication()` data locally and deal with my queries with that locally saved instance. So, I tried this:

```
private lazy var dummyApp: XCUIApplication = {
   return XCUIApplication()
}()
```

Here, I used a lazy variable(because I want to call the `XCUIApplication()` only once to stop the system from taking the snapshots) that returns `XCUIApplication()` instance and tried to print the cell counts like:

```
dummyApp.tables.firstMatch.cells.count
```

This also throwing the same error.

**Question:**

Is there a way to save `XCUIApplication()`'s whole structure with a local variable? Or can I stop/extend the snapshot process before accessing an element?

P.S: I'm using Xcode 11.3.1. I'm facing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429118/ui-testing-fails-with-error-failed-to-get-snapshot-within-15-0s) issue for a long time. Posting this problem as a separate question since XCUITest changed its interaction with the application from Xcode 9.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**:

You can use

```
let snapshot = app.snapshot()
```

Which gives you a snapshot of the app and all the elements and subelements.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementsnapshot
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementattributes

---

Talking about performance.

Your UITableView is too big for black-box testing frameworks like XCTest (Appium, Katalon Studio etc).

If you want to test it, you should consider switching to EarlGrey 2.0 (or other grey-box frameworks). The good thing is you can use EarlGrey 2.0 alongside your existing XCTest tests.

You can read more about testing frameworks performance in this article https://devexperts.com/blog/ios-ui-testing-frameworks-performance-comparison/

P.S. Such big tables are also bad for users. Consider redesigning your UI.

Comment: you can't use app.snapshot() if it times out.